# Indicator icons on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, icons, indicator

[image]

I want to ask about the app indicator on Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed topicon plus extension but only one of my application icon appears to this extension (Pidgin). Others applications like Viber, mailspring, Skype, Slack… are displayed more to the left.

If I click with the left mouse button on the Pidgin icon, it toggles show/hide application. When I click with left mouse on icons on left (Viber, Slack…) it displays the application menu.

In 17.10 it worked perfectly and all applications are showed in topicon plus extension.

Is here a way to have toggle show/hide for all application icons?